# How to run multiple copies of another program - C

Tags: c

I have 2 files file1.c and file2.c
I want to run multiple copies of **file1.c** From My main file **file2.c**

Comment: Are you aware that C files and programs are different things?

Comment: Are you talking about threads, multiple processes, or just calling the functions within testsim multiple times in a row in runsum?  This will be closed too broad quickly without this information.

Comment: @DietrichEpp yes I'm aware.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan
I want to Write a test program called testsim that takes two command-line arguments the sleep time and the repeat factor. 
After that I want to run multiple copies of the testsim.c From runsim.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the system calls [fork()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) and [exec()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exec). A fork allows to copy the current process and all its memory. An exec call allows to replace to code to execute for the current process.

Basically, from your main process, you would fork multiple times. If the result of fork is 0, call exec with the command line for your child process.

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // fork() returns 0 for the child process, 
    // and the actual pid of the new process for the parent process.
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (!pid) {
        // This if will be executed only by the child process.

        // execvp() first argument is the executable file,
        // the second argument is a varargs for each arguments of the command line.
        execvp("testsim");
    }
}
```

However, for this to work, both c files must be compiled into executables.

Comment: If the given c files are passed into exevp, it won't work very well :)  We are not quite sure what level OP is at with the question...

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Can u tell me your email. Let me share problem in detail with you.

Comment: @sturcotte06 needs your email also.

Answer (score 0):

use `system()` to execute an executable from another executable.

Add this line in your **runsim.c**

```
system("path_to_testsim_executable/testsim_executable_name");
```

Call the above line according to how many times you want to run the **testsim**.

And now compile both the `.c` files and run the `runsim` executable.

Comment: Thanks can you share your email. I want to share the problem in detail with you.

Comment: Can't run in my case
executable name **hello** But when i run system("hello");
it output
hello: not found

Comment: @Sheri Are you sure your executable name of `testsim.c` is `hello` instead of `a.out` like you get in unix? And you must provide path to the executable. you can't just write `hello` there. I just saw you have accepted an answer. That means you already got the solution. Am I need to explain additionally after you have got your solution?

Comment: @Sheri Sorry... I can't help you after you got your solution(technically).